# Android Studio 1.5.1 добавить в проект библиотеку .so

Tags: android, android-studio

Недавно начал изучать программирование под андроид.
Столкнулся с вопросом как подключить библиотеки .so, начиная с импорта до вызова функций.
есть три версии библиотеки:
armeabi,
armeabi-v7a,
x86

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить их в папку `app/src/main/libs/${EABI}/${LIBNAME}`, где `${EABI}` это архитектура, например `armeabi-v7a`, а `${LIBNAME}` это название библиотеки, например `libirrlicht.so`
После этого, необходимо указать в файле `build.gradle` путь к библиотекам:

```
android {
    // Остальной код в секции android
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //отключаем автоматическую попытку сборки библиотек из исходников
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
    // Остальной код в секции android
}
```

После чего, в файле исходников, в котором собираетесь использовать функции из библиотеки, добавьте соответствующие определения функций.
Например, если у вас есть класс `com.MainActivity`, в котором определена функция

```
public native void nativeOnCreate();
```

то вам необходимо иметь в библиотеке соответствующую функцию

```
void Java_com_MainActivity_nativeOnCreate( JNIEnv*  env )
{

}
```

с которой вы и будете работать в приложении, осуществляя вызов `nativeOnCreate()`

Comment: А как мне посмотреть какие есть функции в библиотеке?

Comment: Если библиотека специально не адаптирована под android, вам м придётся самому написать эти функции, единственной задачей которых будет вызвать правильные функции в библиотеке. Если же библиотека адаптирована, то скорее с ней уже идёт jar-файл с классами для работы с нативным кодом

Comment: есть .java файл с сигнатурами функций, как его подключить?

Comment: Просто добавьте его в проект. Ключевой момент в том, что этот файл должен находиться в правильном пакете внутри приложения, т.к. на стороне нативного кода название функции определяется положением класса в определённом пакете

Comment: добавил файл, в нем определяются ошибки, наверно не правильный адрес

Comment: К несчастью, без информации о библиотеке, листинга заголовочного файла библиотеки и листинга (хотя бы частичного) файла с сигнатурами, этот разговор сродни сломанному телефону, либо телепатии.

Comment: использую библиотеку bass. после синхронизации gradle, появилась папка jniLibls c библиотеками.

Comment: При добавлении файла bass.java, в   нем все функции с с комментариями :Cannot Resolve Corresponding JNI Function

Comment: сигнатуры bass.java:
 public static native boolean BASS_SetConfig(int option, int value);
 public static native int BASS_GetConfig(int option);
 public static native boolean BASS_SetConfigPtr(int option, Object value);
 public static native Object BASS_GetConfigPtr(int option);

Comment: @IlyaGulya, а неужели вообще нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки, если известен их интерфейс? Что если так - создаёте свой .cpp с функциями, которые перебрасывают вызов на функции подключенной .so? Напимер, 'void Java_com_MainActivity_nativeAdd( JNIEnv*  env, jint a, jint b)
{
  return add(a, b);
}'

Comment: @Eugene именно это я и предложил выше :) 
Если у вас есть заголовочные файлы необходимой библиотеки, ничего не мешает вам написать свою обёртку для подключения библиотеки через jni